# MongoDB: sharded systems cannot enforce cluster-wide unique indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

from the mongoDB docs (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/) I'm reading

> sharded systems cannot enforce cluster-wide unique indexes unless the
>   unique field is in the shard key.

I'm not shure to understand well.
If I have the following unique index
{a,b,c,d}
and the sharded key
{a,b},

is the uniqueness of {a,b,c,d} respected across all the cluster?

Answer (score 2):

Since the shard key is a prefix of the unique key, this uniqueness is preserved.  The key insight is that each chunk exists on exactly one shard.

The uniqueness constraint is that if you have two different documents both with a, b, c, and d all being equal, they should not both exist, because they are not unique.  But since they both have the same values for a and b, they must be in the same chunk, and therefore they would be on the same shard.  That shard does have a unique index on {a:1, b:1, c:1, d:1}, so it will maintain the uniqueness invariant for those two documents, and would not allow you to insert the second one.

So:

> is the uniqueness of {a,b,c,d} respected across all the cluster?

Yes.